# Executar Javascript após chamada AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax

Olá, estou carregando uma página para dentro de uma div através do AJAX, para que os dados possam ser carregados sem a necessidade de recarregar a página. No entanto, percebi que o javascript que estiver nesta página carregada não é executado. Preciso fazer com que alguns scripts sejam executados somente quando a página referente a ele seja carregada para dentro desta div. Estou tentando da seguinte forma:

```
<li onclick="callref('exchange'); marcaLinha();" class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link"><i class="fa fa-exchange"></i><span>Comércio</span></a></li>
```

Nesta linha, "callref" é a função que coloca a página "exchange" dentro da div. Esta função está funcionando normalmente. A função "marcaLinha" é um trecho de código que supostamente deveria selecionar a linha de uma tabela que fica dentro da página exchange, no entanto eu tenho o seguinte erro: Uncaught ReferenceError: marcaLinha is not defined at HTMLLIElement.onclick

A função "marcaLinha" está com o seguinte código:

```
function marcaLinha() {
var tabela = document.getElementById("tab_comandas");
var linhas = tabela.getElementsByTagName("tr");

for (var i = 0; i < linhas.length; i++) {
    var linha = linhas[i];
    linha.addEventListener("click", function() {
        //Adicionar ao atual
        selLinha(this, false); //Selecione apenas um
        //selLinha(this, true); //Selecione quantos quiser
    });
}
```

A função acima foi feita baseada em um tutorial que vi na internet, ao executar ela em um arquivo separado para teste ela funcionou corretamente, no entanto, ao fazer desta forma, estou tendo problemas.

As duas funções estão em um mesmo arquivo  javascript, então creio que a falha não é referente a importação do arquivo, visto que a função "callref" funciona corretamente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quem interessar possa, consegui solucionar o problema. Chamei a função logo na criação da tabela, da seguinte forma:

```
                    <?php
                $sql = 'select * from CAD_VENDAS where STATUS=0;';
                $query = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
                if (mysqli_num_rows($query) >= 1) {
                    while ($resultado = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
                        echo '
                                        <tr>
                                            <td></td>
                                            <td onclick="marcaLinha()">' . $resultado['COMANDA'] . '</td>
                                            <td onclick="marcaLinha()">' . $resultado['NOME_CLI'] . '</td>
                                        </tr>                   
                                        ';
                    }
                } else {
                    echo '<h2>Nenhum registro encontrado.</h2>';
                }
                ?>
```